# Using a generic type passed without constraint with a constrained generic type

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Lets say we have the following classes:

```
public interface IFrobnicator<T> { }

class ComparableFrobnicator<T> : IFrobnicator<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public ComparableFrobnicator(T value) { }
}

class EquatableFrobnicator<T> : IFrobnicator<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    public EquatableFrobnicator(T value) { }
}
```

You can write methods

```
public IFrobnicator<T> MakeFrobnicatorFromComparable<T>(T value) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return new ComparableFrobnicator<T>(value);
}

public IFrobnicator<T> MakeFrobnicatorFromEquatable<T>(T value) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return new EquatableFrobnicator<T>(value);
}
```

If I wanted to unify that into a single method, the most obvious way won't compile:

```
public IFrobnicator<T> MakeFrobnicator<T>(T value)
{
    if (value is IComparable<T>)
    {
        return new ComparableFrobnicator<T>(value);
    }
    else if (value is IEquatable<T>)
    {
        return new EquatableFrobnicator<T>(value);
    }
    else throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

That raises the following error when compiled:

> CS0314 The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UserQuery.ComparableFrobnicator'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable'.

I can't replace `new ComparableFrobnicator <T>` with `new ComparableFrobnicator<IComparable<T>>` because that causes problems down the line with getting `value` back out - you cannot cast from an interface type to a concrete type.

So instead, I went the route of reflection:

```
public IFrobnicator<T> MakeFrobnicator<T>(T value)
{
    if (value is IComparable<T>)
    {
        var constructor = typeof(ComparableFrobnicator<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(T) });
        return (IFrobnicator<T>)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { value});
    }
    else if (value is IEquatable<T>)
    {
        var constructor = typeof(EquatableFrobnicator<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(T) });
        return (IFrobnicator<T>)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { value });
    }
    else throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

That seems to work perfectly, but looks like a step backwards in a language with such powerful type inference as I'm used to.  Is there something I'm missing, or a better technique I missed?

Comment: In your combined method, value is of type T as a parameter, then you see if value's type is IComparable<T> or IEquatable<T>. Something's not right there.

Comment: @David e.g. `int`, is `IComparable<int>` *and* `IEquatable<int>`. A type representing complex numbers could be equatable to itself, but not comparable.

Comment: It seems that last method should be constrained to the IComparable

Comment: @valery.sntx `Point` implements `IEquatable<Point>` but not `IComparable`. What if I need to frobnicate `Point`s?

Comment: Could you explain with a more concrete example? What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ErikE it's a wrapper around `T1 : IComparable<T2>` or `T2 : IComparable<T1>` to implement comparison operators on classes only implementing `IComparable`. I can post the full code when it isn't 1am.

Comment: @ErikE [I extended on this question with some more concrete code here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36155997/1894317)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the extention methods approach, 
The way **value.MakeFrobnicator()** is implemented helps to resolve generic type params issue

```
public interface IFrobnicator<T> { }

public class ComparableFrobnicator<T> :IFrobnicator<T> 
                              where T  :IComparable<T> 
 {
    public ComparableFrobnicator(T param) { }
 }

public class EquatableFrobnicator<T> :IFrobnicator<T>
                              where T : IEquatable<T> 
{
   public EquatableFrobnicator(T value) { }
}

 public static class FrobnicatorExtentions
 {
    public static IFrobnicator<T> 
          MakeFrobnicatorFromComparable<T>(this T value)
    where T: IComparable<T>
    {                                                            
      //return new ComparableFrobnicator<T>(value);      
     return value.MakeFrobnicator();
    }

    public static IFrobnicator<T> 
           MakeFrobnicatorFromEquatable<T>(this T value)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
      // return new EquatableFrobnicator<T>(value);
     return value.MakeFrobnicator();
    }  

    public static IFrobnicator<T> 
                  MakeFrobnicator<T>(this IEquatable<T> value) 
    where T: IEquatable<T>
    {
      if (value is T)
      {
        if (value is IEquatable<T>)
        {
          return new EquatableFrobnicator<T>((T)value);
        } 
      }

     throw new InvalidCastException();
    }

   public static IFrobnicator<T> 
                 MakeFrobnicator<T>(this IComparable<T> value) 
   where T : IComparable<T>
  {
     if (value is T)
     {
       if (value is IComparable<T>)
       {
         return new ComparableFrobnicator<T>((T)value);
      }
     }

    throw new InvalidCastException();
  }

}
```

Comment: That looks like it works.  Now to see if I can expand it to my specific case.

Comment: You can remove the `value is IComparable<T>` etc checks: they're always true, by the method signature.

Comment: @RoadieRich thanks for accepting my answer, agree 'value is IComparable<T>' left from old refactoring loop

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a cast?

```
public IFrobnicator<T> MakeFrobnicator<T>(T value)
{
    if (value is IComparable<T>)
    {
        return new ComparableFrobnicator<T>((IComparable<T>)value);
    }
    else if (value is IEquatable<T>)
    {
        return new EquatableFrobnicator<T>((IEquatable<T>)value);
    }
    else throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

I can't remember off the top of my head if that's at all valid. Either way, it's not very open/closed. You could instead write a list of converters that each decide if they are the appropriate type to do the conversion.

Comment: That won't compile either. `ComparableFrobnicator<T>` is the problem.

Comment: Using `is` then casting does extra operations. Instead, do `var comparable = value as IComparable; if (comparable != null)`.