# Type Inference between generics with reversed constraints

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

This is an extension from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36145569/1894317), which had an answer that works in that specific case.

My actual code looks more like this:

```
public abstract class BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>
{ }

public class LeftComparable<TLeft, TRight> : BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight> where TLeft : IComparable<TRight>
{
    public LeftComparable(TLeft value) { }
}

public class RightComparable<TLeft, TRight> : BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight> where TRight : IComparable<TLeft>
{
    public RightComparable(TLeft value) { }
}
```

If you use the equivalent reflection code to what I posted, it works great:

```
public static BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight> AsComparableFor<TLeft, TRight>(this TLeft left, TRight right)
{
    if (left is IComparable<TRight>)
    {
        var constructor =
            typeof(LeftComparable<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TLeft), typeof(TRight))
                                      .GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(TLeft) });
        if (constructor != null)
        {
            return (BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { left });
        }
    }
    if (right is IComparable<TLeft>)
    {
        var constructor =
            typeof(RightComparable<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TLeft), typeof(TRight))
                                      .GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(TLeft) });
        if (constructor != null)
        {
            return (BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { left });
        }
    }
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Then you can say

```
class Baz
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
class Bar : IComparable<Baz>
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    int IComparable<Baz>.CompareTo(Baz other)
    {
        return Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
    }
}

// ....

var bar = new Bar { Value = 1 };
var baz = new Baz { Value = 1 };
var compBaz = baz.AsComparableFor(bar);
var compBar = bar.AsComparableFor(baz);
```

Fantastic, type inference works exactly as expected.

The adaptation from the accepted answer above, however,

```
public static class Comparable
{
    public static BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>
                  AsComparableFor<TLeft, TRight>(this IComparable<TRight> left, TRight right)
    where TLeft : IComparable<TRight>
    {
        if (left is TLeft)
        {
            if (left is IComparable<TRight>)
            {
                return new LeftComparable<TLeft, TRight>((TLeft)left);
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }

    public static BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>
                  AsComparableFor<TLeft, TRight>(this TLeft left, IComparable<TLeft> right)
    where TRight : IComparable<TLeft>
    {
        if (left is TLeft)
        {
            if (right is IComparable<TLeft>)
            {
                return new RightComparable<TLeft, TRight>((TLeft)left);
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
}
```

Requires you to explicitly state the type arguments:

```
//bar.AsComparableFor(baz);
//baz.AsComparableFor(bar); //Does not compile

bar.AsComparableFor<Bar, Baz>(baz);
baz.AsComparableFor<Baz, Bar>(bar); // Does compile
```

A big part of this was to make the library as painless as possible, and I feel having to specify types defeats that somewhat.

Is there a middle ground?  Can I get the cleaner, reflectionless code from the accepted answer with the type inference strength of the original?

Edit: [full code can be found in this gist.](https://gist.github.com/RoadieRich/8ffbf6ac08fedd39c528)

Comment: How can you know at compile-time the properties to compare (`int Value`), but only know at run-time which classes you'll be comparing? This seems like a disconnect. It seems like you could construct your comparable class in advance rather than inserting its information at run-time. Plus, having to do all that type checking is ugly. Perhaps that's not avoidable, but yikes. I wish you could make this even more concrete. Why the need for comparing disparate classes?

Comment: @ErikE `[Left|Right]Comparable` and `Comparable` are library classes.  `Bar` and `Baz` are just examples from what would be user code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I get the cleaner, reflectionless code from the accepted answer with the type inference strength of the original?

You can't. Actually the accepted answer is not good because it involves value type boxing.

So again, you cannot avoid reflection. What you can do though is to **minimize** the reflection by using the same technique as in `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,d8e28972e89a3e86), `Comparer<T>.Default` etc. The only difference would be that instead of creating a singleton instance, we'll create a singleton factory delegate:

```
public abstract class BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>
{
    public static readonly Func<TLeft, BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>> Factory = CreateFactory();
    private static Func<TLeft, BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>> CreateFactory()
    {
        Type genericTypeDefinition;
        if (typeof(IComparable<TRight>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TLeft)))
            genericTypeDefinition = typeof(LeftComparable<,>);
        else if (typeof(IComparable<TLeft>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TRight)))
            genericTypeDefinition = typeof(RightComparable<,>);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException();
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLeft), "value");
        var body = Expression.New(genericTypeDefinition
            .MakeGenericType(typeof(TLeft), typeof(TRight))
            .GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(TLeft) }), parameter);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TLeft, BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>>>(body, parameter);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}


public static class BaseComparable
{
    public static BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight> AsComparableFor<TLeft, TRight>(this TLeft left, TRight right)
    {
        return BaseComparable<TLeft, TRight>.Factory(left);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer this way over my refection version, other than "This is how the framework does it" - which, in itself, must have a good reason?

Comment: Performance. It's a one time only reflection per <TLeft, TRight> pair.

Comment: Ah, so it's implicitly caching/memoizing... that was something I was considering adding anyway.

Comment: Basically you get that "caching" behavior for free with generic class static fields.